# How do I get the bin bag (trash bag) outside without it dripping all over me?

Tags: home

The bin bags (trash bags) I have just bought in a roll of 100 of have small holes in the bottom, presumably so that they can compress when tied off. The downside of this is that if the bin contains something liquid, or something that has become liquid, it leaks out of the bottom when I take the bin bag out of the bin.

Is there a way of avoiding this very unpleasant situation?

Comment: How much tape do you have? ;)

Comment: what kind of dumb bags are these, so that I know never to buy them?

Comment: Trash bags with holes in the bottom… Genius at its peak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem for years, and have opted to buy new bins last year. There are a lot of bins sporting extra removable buckets in them (has something to do with being able to clean them better).
When the time arrives to clean my bins, I just take the removable bucket outside, tie off my trash bag, throw it away and take the removable bucket back in the house.

An old study-partner of mine always put a real bucket on the bottom of his trashcan, because he always punctured his trash bag at the bottom so it was easier to remove from the trashcan. The bucket would contain the liquids and he only had to clean that instead of the whole trashcan!

Answer (score 3):

Use two bags per load. When the bin is full, tie off the top tightly, so that nothing can leak out, and then open another bag over the top, dumping the first bag into the second. Tie it off, and carry it off. The first bag should be upside down inside the second.

Pro: You use up the nasty bags twice as fast! :P

Comment: If it is possible to tie the top so tightly that it does not leak, why not just tie the top and carry the single bag upside down?

Comment: @MattGiltaji That would be gross, and also, liquid eventually gets through a knot, so the second bag will help a little with that. Putting a paper towel at the bottom of the second bag can also help.

Answer (score 3):

Cover all of the holes with a few big pieces of plastic wrap or aluminum foil. Use duct tape to secure it.

**Alternative Solution**

Before placing any trash in the trash bag, place a wad of newspaper at the bottom of the bag. This will help to absorb any juices that are in the bag.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell me, you can predict what could be the cause of the leak? Then you can just put all the possible leakers (I don't think you would have really many of them) in additinal small cellophane bags. I, for example, have a big roll of those bags and sometimes use them in the case something I bin would leak.

Answer (score 1):

- Double up bags (more wasteful)
- Cover each hole with an "X" of duct tape after unfolding the bag and before lining the can.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the number of small holes, option #2 may not work.

Comment: @J.Musser The OP should provide more details then.

Comment: Fair enough.‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 1):

Instead of walking about with a bin bag, take the indoor bin with you when you need to empty it.

Then, once outside, transfer the bag from the indoor to the outdoor bin in one smooth steady motion.

By limiting the amount of time the bin bag is jostling about, you should reduce the amount of sloshing of the liquid within it.

Another advantage is that you're now outside to tip away any bin juice that may be in the bottom of the bin too.