# How can I prevent the bin bag falling into the bin?

Tags: home, plastics, trash

Further to my other [bin-related woes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/how-do-i-get-the-bin-bag-trash-bag-outside-without-it-dripping-all-over-me), sometimes, when the bin* is getting full (but not overfull - there's still room in there), the edges of the bin bag will slip down, making it a disgusting job having to fish them out to tie off the bag.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this situation?

---

* *Garbage can, for those Americans out there.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a band and tie it around the bag and container so the bag is now held up. This works better if you have a rim on the container. What usually works for me is:

- Rubber Bands
- Paracord tied
- Any cheap rope, because you can just pitch it afterwards.

[Thrifty fun:](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf92529215.tip.html)

- Binder Clips-

> One day, I took binder clips (the black or colored clips with silver
>   bars that you get in office supply stores) and used two clips, one on
>   each side on the garbage can rim, clipping the bag to the can. I
>   flipped the bars down. They easily went on and I was able to close the
>   lid. It has worked like a charm. I can now use any type of bag that is
>   on sale. By Shardebhow from Cherry Hill, NJ

- Using elastic- You can take elastic and wrap a length around the container.
- Use the right size bags. If you use a large bag on a small container it falls in.

Also, make tape handles for the bag and attach to the outside of the container.

Answer (score 6):

After you've put the liner in the bin, pull the bag tight, twist it a few times and tuck it back under itself

[image]
[image]

Comment: I never thought to tie it like this. 1+ it is easier to take a loose than regular knots.

Comment: Janitorial staff have been doing this for decades. It works.